# Are Laravel model relations query every time?

Tags: php, laravel

This is a model

```
class User {

   $table = 'users';

   public function item()
   {
        return $this->hasOne('Item');
   }


}
```

the I make a loop getting the item:

```
foreach($users as $user)
{

  echo $user->item->name;

}
```

are this user model querying the item each loop?

so if yes will this be the same?

```
class User {

   $table = 'users';

   public function item()
   {
        return Item::where('user_id', '=', $this->id)->first();
   }


}
```

in other words will be the first class method item the same as the second class method item? or is there a difference in performance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are worried about performance, use User::with('item').

[eloquent eager loading](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#eager-loading)